# How to use the same code in every ActiveX checkbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I want ActiveX checkboxes for filling rows and columns of a sheet.
I created a macro for the first checkbox.
I want to fill the rest of the sheet with checkboxes that process the same code as the first one.

Below is my example.

[image]

Working code of the ActiveX checkbox that works in cell `B2`

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then    
        Shell "cmd.exe /c E:" & "gam update group " & (Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column)) & " add member " & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))    
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Value = False Then    
        Shell "cmd.exe /c E:" & "gam update group " & (Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column)) & " delete user " & Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    End If    
End Sub
```

How can all the other checkboxes run the same code without having to copy/paste it into each checkbox?

Keep in mind, I am going to have hundreds of checkboxes on this sheet doing the same thing.

Comment: Is this what you want? [VBA – Control Arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try worksheetchange event and loop for each checkbox ...

Comment: This event does not fire when a checkbox is checked or unchecked though.